# NUL-byte between every other character in output

Tags: powershell, encoding

I'm using Ruby to read and then print a file to stdout, redirecting the output to a file in Windows PowerShell.

However, when I inspect the files, I get this for the input:

```
PS D:> head -n 1 .\inputfile
<text id="http://observer.guardian.co.uk/osm/story/0,,1009777,00.html">         <s>             Hooligans       NNS     hooligan
                ,       ,       ,               unbridled       JJ      unbridled               passion NN      passion
-       :       -               and     CC      and             no      DT      no              executive       JJ      executiv
e               boxes   NNS     box             .       SENT    .               </s>
```

... yet this for the output:

```
PS D:> head -n 1 .\outputfile
ÿ_< t e x t   i d = " h t t p : / / o b s e r v e r . g u a r d i a n . c o . u k / o s m / s t o r y / 0 , , 1 0 0 9 7 7 7 , 0
0 . h t m l " >                  < s >           H o o l i g a n s       N N S   h o o l i g a n                 ,       ,
 ,               u n b r i d l e d       J J     u n b r i d l e d               p a s s i o n   N N     p a s s i o n
 -       :       -               a n d   C C     a n d           n o     D T     n o             e x e c u t i v e       J J
 e x e c u t i v e               b o x e s       N N S   b o x           .       S E N T         .               < / s >
```

How can this happen?

---

**Edit**: since my problem didn't have anything to do with Ruby, I've removed the Ruby-code, and included my usage of the Windows shell.

Comment: What is your platform? That [`ÿ_`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) sure looks like a BOM for UTF-16 output.

Comment: Don't know why but your output file seems to be UTF-16 encoded.

Comment: Thanks! I'd never have guessed the meaning of the `ÿ_`. I fear it's Windows-specific, and has nothing to do with Ruby. The NUL-bytes made me suspect UTF-16, and problem is indeed solved when I have Ruby output in UTF-16... and use Ruby's file-out instead of PowerShell's `>` operator.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In PowerShell `>` is effectively the same as `| Out-File` and Out-File defaults to Unicode encoding. Try this instead of using `>`:

```
... | Out-File outputfile -encoding ASCII
```

Comment: Thank you, this pretty much explains why everything suddenly went crazy when I switched to PowerShell! ^^

Comment: Is there a way to do this globally instead of specifying `-encoding` for every `Out-File` call?

Comment: Also I just noticed Out-File -Append is more likely to cause this issue than just plain Out-File.

Comment: Doesn't `>` default to whatever the codepage of the console is (like `cmd`)?  It's not an alias for `| Out-File`