# SQLCMD outputting text with spaces between letters

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that takes some inputs and uses them in a SQLCMD call, putting the output into a log file.

```
SQLCMD -Q $RestoreDB -S $SQLServer -d $DBName >> $SQLLogFile
```

The log file is a .txt file, but when I run this the output of the script (in this case, some information related to the restore process) is very odd:

```
C h a n g e d   d a t a b a s e   c o n t e x t   t o   ' m a s t e r ' . 

 N o n q u a l i f i e d   t r a n s a c t i o n s   a r e   b e i n g   r o l l e d   b a c k .       E s t i m a t e d   r o l l b a c k   c o m p l e t i o n :   1 0 0 % . 

 1 0   p e r c e n t   p r o c e s s e d . 

 2 0   p e r c e n t   p r o c e s s e d . 

 3 0   p e r c e n t   p r o c e s s e d .
```

I think this is because Powershell uses unicode, so these are 2-byte characters (hence the space). Is there any way to change the way Powershell outputs, or should I pipe the output from SQLCMD using `out-file -append` and just change it there?

Comment: Does `Out-File -Encoding Ascii` work for you?

Comment: Absolutely, but I'm hoping for a way to change things more globally rather than have to change every instance where I put data into a log file.

Comment: The technet page says that Unicode is default. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [NUL-byte between every other character in output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147179/nul-byte-between-every-other-character-in-output) Maybe this will help

Comment: Would making a small cmdlet for this not be a solution? You could place it in your profile. Or is that cheating what you want to accomplish? Or just use `Set-Content` or `Add-Content`

Comment: You can also usually change the encoding of a file after the fact with `(Get-Content $filename) | Out-File $filename -Encoding $newencoding`.  Note that the parens are required if you're reading and writing to the same file.  If the filenames are different, you should omit them for better performance.

Comment: That would actually be a great way to handle it. I can put that in my post-processing function.

Comment: I would actually recommend using SMO instead of the old busted `SQLCMD`. Last I checked, SQLCMD still didn't support spaces in file names. SMO will also let you bind to events and such just as you would in C#