# Out-File -append in Powershell does not produce a new line and breaks string into characters

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to understand some weird behaviour with this cmdlet.

If I use "Out-File -append Filename.txt" on a text file that I created and entered text into via the windows context menu, the string will append to the last line in that file as a series of space separated characters.

So:

```
"This is a test" | out-file -append textfile.txt
```

Will produce:
T h i s  i s  a  t e s t

This wont happen if out-file creates the file, or if the text file has no text in it prior to appending. Why does this happen?

I will also note that repeating the command will just append in the same way to the same line. I guess it doesn't recognise newline or line break terminator or something due to changed encoding?

Comment: `Out-File` defaults to unicode encoding by default. Use `-Encoding Ascii`.   In your case `out-file -Encoding Ascii -append textfile.txt`. Add-Content uses ascii by default and also appends by default. `"This is a test" | Add-Content textfile.txt`. You did not send a newline so it will not write one to file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NUL-byte between every other character in output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147179/nul-byte-between-every-other-character-in-output)

Comment: @Matt You should have just made your first comment an answer and considered the issue resolved.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Never sure if it is worth answering duplicate questions

Comment: @Matt If it's worded differently enough I think it helps more people find answers since everyone searches differently.

Comment: Truly works, here my example: { Test-NetConnection -ComputerName xxx.xx.xxx.com -CommonTCPPort HTTP | Out-File -append httpportscan.txt }

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`Out-File` defaults to unicode encoding which is why you are seeing the behavior you are. Use `-Encoding Ascii` to change this behavior. In your case

```
Out-File -Encoding Ascii -append textfile.txt.
```

`Add-Content` uses Ascii and also appends by default.

```
"This is a test" | Add-Content textfile.txt.
```

As for the lack of newline: You did not send a newline so it will not write one to file.

Comment: How do I do the reverse of this. for Add-Content if I want it to add in unicode?

Comment: @GideonSassoon `Add-Content` also supports the `-Encoding` parameter.

Comment: Actually, `Out-File` does write a new line. There is an explicit option to switch it off: `-NoNewline`.

Answer (score 0):

Add-Content is default ASCII and add new line however Add-Content brings locked files issues too.