# Running SSIS packages with Powershell and piping output to a log file -> Spaces inserted into log results

Tags: powershell, ssis

I've got a powershell script on my windows server running an SSIS package, using an xml config that outputs to a log file.

Sometimes when I run this script, the output to the log file doesn't seem to be written to the log correctly, and it appears as though the powershell script inserts spaces between each character of the log as it's being written.

Does anyone know why this behavior may be occurring?

My Powershell script:

```
dtexec /f "D:/Batch Jobs/ThisJob/ThisJob.dtsx" /conf "D:\Batch Jobs\ThisJob\ThisJob.dtsconfig."  >> "D:/Batch Jobs/ThisJob/ThisJob_executionlog.txt"
```

Example of normal output:

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 12.0.4100.1
>   for 64-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Started:  11:42:19 AM Progress: 2016-05-26 11:42:19.53    Source:
>   AM_AGENT     Validating: 0% complete

Example of powershell output peppered with spaces:

> M i c r o s o f t   ( R )   S Q L   S e r v e r   E x e c u t e   P a
>   c k a g e   U t i l i t y     V e r s i o n   1 2 . 0 . 4 1 0 0 . 1
>   f o r   6 4 - b i t     C o p y r i g h t   ( C )   M i c r o s o f t 
>   C o r p o r a t i o n .   A l l   r i g h t s   r e s e r v e d .
>
> ```
>  S t a r t e d :     1 2 : 5 1 : 1 3   P M     P r o g r e s s :   2 0 1 6 - 0 5 - 2 6   1 2 : 5 1 : 1 3 . 8 0 
>
>    S o u r c e :   A M _ A G E N T   
>
>    V a l i d a t i n g :   0 %   c o m p l e t e     E n d   P r o g r e s s     P r o g r e s s :   2 0 1 6 - 0 5 - 2 6   1 2 : 5 1 : 1 3 . 8 6 
>
>    S o u r c e :   A M _ A G E N T   
>
>    V a l i d a t i n g :   5 0 %   c o m p l e t e     E n d   P r o g r e s s     P r o g r e s s :   2 0 1 6 - 0 5 - 2 6   1 2 : 5 1 :
> ```
>
> 1 3 . 8 6
>
> ```
>    S o u r c e :   A M _ A G E N T   
>
>    V a l i d a t i n g :   1 0 0 %   c o m p l e t e     E n d   P r o g r e s s     P r o g r e s s :   2 0 1 6 - 0 5 - 2 6   1 2 : 5 1
> ```
>
> : 1 3 . 8 6
>
> ```
>    S o u r c e :   A M _ A
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `| Out-File path` instead of `>>`?

Comment: It appears as though that's the ticket! I'm a total powershell noob, so I'm gonna test this out a few more times but it appears as though this meets my need! Thank you Andrey Marchuk!!! :) I think this does it! I will mark your response as the answer shortly. I appreciate your response to this question! Thank you so much

Comment: After testing this out with -Append on the out-file, it seems like the spacing issue happens again... Dang it! Any idea on appending to out-file and preventing this issue?

Comment: It appears as though adding '-Encoding Ascii' as a parameter of this process, a-la http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413264/out-file-append-in-powershell-does-not-produce-a-new-line-and-breaks-string-int gets this problem taken care of. :) Thanks again Andrey!